# Can Anyone Decipher a .htaccess File?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wordpress

This is my current .Htaccess File:

```
AddType application/java .class .class
AddType application/javascript .js2 .js2
AddType application/json .json .json
AddType application/msword .doc .docx .doc .docx
AddType application/pdf .pdf .pdf
AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb .mdb
AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot .eot
AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp .mpp
AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri .wri
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc .odc
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb .odb
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf .odf
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg .odg
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp .odp
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods .ods
AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt .odt
AddType application/x-font-otf .otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc .ttf .ttc
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip .gz .gzip
AddType application/x-javascript .js .js
AddType application/x-msdownload .exe .exe
AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf .swf
AddType application/x-tar .tar .tar
AddType application/zip .zip .zip
AddType audio/midi .mid .midi .mid .midi
AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a .mp3 .m4a
AddType audio/ogg .ogg .ogg
AddType audio/wav .wav .wav
AddType audio/wma .wma .wma
AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram .ra .ram
AddType image/bmp .bmp .bmp
AddType image/gif .gif .gif
AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe .jpg .jpeg .jpe
AddType image/png .png .png
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz .svg .svgz
AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff .tif .tiff
AddType image/x-icon .ico .ico
AddType text/css .css .css
AddType text/html .html .htm .html .htm
AddType text/javascript .js3 .js3
AddType text/plain .txt .txt
AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx .rtf .rtx
AddType text/x-component .htc .htc
AddType text/x-js .js4 .js4
AddType text/xml .xml .xml
AddType text/xsd .xsd .xsd
AddType text/xsl .xsl .xsl
AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
AddType video/avi .avi .avi
AddType video/divx .divx .divx
AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe .mpeg .mpg .mpe
AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt .mov .qt


# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType text/x-component .htc
    AddType application/x-javascript .js
    AddType application/javascript .js2
    AddType text/javascript .js3
    AddType text/x-js .js4
    AddType text/html .html .htm
    AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
    AddType text/plain .txt
    AddType text/xsd .xsd
    AddType text/xsl .xsl
    AddType text/xml .xml
    AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
    AddType video/avi .avi
    AddType image/bmp .bmp
    AddType application/java .class
    AddType video/divx .divx
    AddType application/msword .doc .docx
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
    AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
    AddType image/gif .gif
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
    AddType application/json .json
    AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
    AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
    AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
    AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
    AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
    AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
    AddType application/x-font-otf .otf
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
    AddType audio/ogg .ogg
    AddType application/pdf .pdf
    AddType image/png .png
    AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
    AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
    AddType application/x-tar .tar
    AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
    AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
    AddType audio/wav .wav
    AddType audio/wma .wma
    AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
    AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
    AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/x-js A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/html A3600
    ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
    ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
    ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/java A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/divx A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/msword A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/json A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/midi A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/tiff A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|htc|js|js2|js3|js4|CSS|HTC|JS|JS2|JS3|JS4)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|json|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|JSON|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN W3TC Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=W3TC_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp\-postpass|w3tc_logged_out|wordpress_logged_in|wptouch_switch_toggle) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/page_enhanced/%{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index.html%{ENV:W3TC_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase //
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My website is static, sitting in my file manager. But I also have wordpress installed on the domain for the use of ONE plugin that still functions even though my site is separate, its a URL masker plugin. But my main website is in static files, homepage is index.html, about page is about.html, and so forth.

Anywho the person who made my site created a re-direct so that any broken url will redirect to the homepage. Such as Mydomain.com/dsg4psdsd  ---> MyDomain.com. I dont know where that re-direct is, I think it will conflict with any code you guys give me to try. So I need to locate that first.

But I want to make a re-redirect that will re-direct 
http://Mydomain.com/ & http://www.MyDomain.com/index.html  to just: **http://www.MyDomain.com/**  Because right now I have essentially 3 urls for my homepage.

- Identify and remove the current re-direct in the htaccess file
- -Re-direct to just 1 homepage URL (http//www.MyDomain.com)
- and to re-direct any non existing .html page in my file manager.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect is probably being done by wordpress, since a request for a resource that doesn't exist will get trapped by the conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

and the request gets routed through `/index.php`, which sees that the request is asking for something that's not there and redirects the browser to the root.

You can redirect as long as the rules are **before any wordpress rules**. Not sure why you have so many wordpress blocks that do essentially the exact same thing, you only need one of them. But before *any of them*, you can add the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^YourDomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html
RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ http://www.YourDomain.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Okay so, Im a noob at this, so to confirm: I should just add The 3 lined code you wrote above to the htaccess file? Is there anything I should also delete from it that is un-needed? -thanks (there's also a cache plugin installed on my wordpress, that might explain all the code)

Comment: @JohnDylan Just add it before all of the `# BEGIN WordPress`.

Comment: Awesome I think it worked so far! Thanks man. And if there's any part of that htaccess code you would recommend removing, let  me know!